# Flask create a file if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, file, flask

I'm trying to create a file in my flask application, but when the file doesn't already exist, the code fails. I've tried the two typical solutions:

```
f = open('f.txt', 'a+')
```

as well as

```
with open('f.txt', 'a+') as f:
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot tell because this application is in production so debugging is not visible to me. All I know is that with these lines above commented out the code runs fine

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: Does it work in dev mode but not production?

Comment: are you getting a permissions error?

Comment: Yep it seems so. Just made a directory with full permissions and it worked fine, thanks a lot! However, I'd prefer to not have a directory fully accessible like that. Is there a way to force Flask to open a file as a particular user?

Comment: No worries, I am not a flask user but I imagine it should be possible to set some write access. Might be a good question to ask on SO.

Comment: The folder doesn't need to be universally writable. It just needs to be writable by the user your application is running as.

Answer (score 0):

Use Access Control Lists, instead of opening that directory to everyone.

```
setfacl -m u:flaskuser:rw /some/dir/
```

Also, check out the documentation on these, it's worth a look : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-acls.html